# Angular routeProvider not loading next template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to have each item in a list have a button that uses $routeProvider to route to a template. However, I keep getting 404s when I hit the link (it goes to the right address, but no page loads). Any help on getting this code to work would be most appreciated:

```
angular.module('tipOutput', ['firebase', 'filters'])
  .controller('Tips', ['$scope', 'angularFire', 
  function ($scope, angularFire) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://sitename.firebaseio.com/tips');
    angularFire(ref, $scope, "tips");
  }])
  //routing to secondary pages
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/tips/:tipId', {template: 'partials/tip-detail.html', controller: 'Tips'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  }])
```

And, in case it helps, here's the code of my template:

```
<html ng-app="TipOutput">
 <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js'></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Routes in a single page app are really virtual routes. How does the webserver software know what to do with that url? What are you doing to map this url to the html file that is serving your app? I suspect you might need to setup your httpd so that it understands what is going on.